# Pass JSON struct from NodeJS to Java Class as a parameter

Tags: javascript, java, json, node.js, jar

I am developing a web app using NodeJS in the backend.

I need to do complex calculations in the backend, for that I am using some classes wiritten in Java. The thing is that I need to call one function of a class written in Java (with parameters), from my NodeJS code.

For that I am using the npm package java.

I can call a java function with a simple array, or String as parameter, and I can get the String returned from java aswell.

Here is an example of code showing how I do the interaction between NodeJS and Java:

NodeJS code:

```
//Import java package
var java = require('java');

//Inside of lib there is a JAR package with all the classes needed
java.classpath.pushDir('lib');

//New instance (package.Class)
java.newInstance("weatherProject.Evaluation", function(err, Evaluation) {
    var arrayToSend = ["one", "two", "three"];

    //Call the JAVA function
    Evaluation.evaluationAlgorithm(arrayToSend, function (err, response) {

        //Output from java (Works if it is a simple String)
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

Here is the Java Class:

```
package weatherProject;

public class Evaluation {

   public String evaluationAlgorithm(String[] input) {

       return input[0] ;
   }

}
```

Using this, how can I pass from the NodeJs code to the Java code a JSON struct, and retrieve it later from Java return? And an Array of Arrays [ ][ ]?

Comment: Java understands JSON format. More specifically, there are libraries that can parse a flat String to usable JSON for Java to process. Jackson, Gson, Jsonlib...

Comment: dowload jackson libraries and put it in your java lib folder. Pass the json as a string to Java class, and the use objectmapper to parse the JSON in Java objects. for using jackson library see the example at http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html